# Android Native Browser : CSS layer tap clicks on

Tags: android, behind

I am building a page for Android, and it uses CSS.  The phone I am testing on right now is ICS.  I've found that in the native browser, when i click on a div with a higher z-index than the page I actually activate the elements behind the divs.  This means that I inadvertently tap ads and links that take me off the page.

This does not happen on the ICS chrome browser though.  Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to remedy this so that my div is what gets tapped?

Thanks,

Comment: I have the same problem. I've noticed that it's also possible to select text in underlying layers, which is very confusing to the user.

Comment: Seems like this bug has been around for years: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6721